# Receiving email with Amazon EC2?

Tags: email, smtp, amazon-ec2

I have no trouble sending out email with my EC2 server, but how can I check the email that is sent to me? I have an elastic IP setup and modified reverse DNS records. Do I need to install Postfix to receive email?

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that port 25 is active and open on  your server.  Install an SMTP service on your instance ...postfix is mighty fine.

Ensure you have also set up some MX records if you want to receive email from the world...

Comment: What other MX records would I need besides mail.domain.com?

Comment: Also, how exactly do I check the email? I have setup postfix and it is running. Which email addresses would work? does %anything%@mydoamin.com will work or do I have to set up each address somehow? And how would I check that specific "box"

Comment: Unless you want people to e-mail you at you@mail.domain.com, you'd want an MX record for domain.com.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the first thing to do is testing if you can open a telnet connection to port 25 on your server. Then you know if anything is listening for incoming mail.

If not, then you should probably install postfix as well as test your firewall settings (I seem to recall the EC2 having some sort of firewall setting for which ports to allow in the web interface)

edit: correct port number

Comment: 110 is not for receiving email.  POP3/IMAP is for reading email that is on a server ... 25 is receiving SMTP