# receiving mail on an ec2 instance (without my own domain)

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that I am using for a test project. I would like to send emails to it but I actually do not need to send emails from it.

I have port 25 open and have installed `mailx` for handling the emails. When I type `mail` i get `No mail for ec2-user` though i have already sent an email there.

My needs are real basic a few emails sent so I don't really need an industrial strength solution.

I know I also need to set up an MX record but this, I think, is where I am getting confused. So the email (at least according to github) is `ec2-user@ip-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal` (x's replace the ip).

When I follow these instructions for setting up the MX record http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/server-configuration/mail-delivery-and-dns-records/what-is-an-mx-record-and-how-is-it-created-1210.html, I get an error:

```
>[ec2-user@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx ~]$ nslookup
> server
Default server: 172.16.x.xx
Address: 172.16.x.xx#53
> set q=MX
> ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal
Server:         172.16.x.xx
Address:        172.16.x.xx#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal: No answer

Authoritative answers can be found from:
us-west-2.compute.internal
    origin = ns0.us-west-2.compute.internal
    mail addr = hostmaster.amazon.com
    serial = 201210xxxx
    refresh = 3600
    retry = 3600
    expire = 3600
    minimum = 60
>
```

again x's where the ip is.

What's a direct way of just setting up the mx record on ec2 so i can receive a few emails? I don't have a domain for this other than what ec2 provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set up an MX record in a domain you don't control... but you do not actually need an MX record when the host receiving the email is the same as the one to which the host is addressed.

You do, however, need to use your EC2 instance's *external* hostname, since the internal one isn't meaningful anywhere except... internally.

This will be in a form more like ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

Using this, you should be able to configure ec2-user@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com as a working email address -- although, for what it's worth, you really shouldn't be using the "ec2-user" account... you should have created one of your own.

You will need more than `mailx` to "handle" the emails; you also need an email server like `exim4` running on your machine, and that server software needs to be configured so that it realizes that ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com is a host for which it should accept incoming email.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you will be able to test this without a domain, short of opening up port 25 and telnetting directly to the port.

Take a look at [Receiving email with Amazon EC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675767/receiving-email-with-amazon-ec2) for some clues as to what you need to get started.